# How to get from '-rw-r--r--' back to 33188?

Tags: python, unix, file-permissions, stat, bitmask

Python has a helper function [`stat.filemode`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1f06a680de465be0c24a78ea3b610053955daa99/Lib/stat.py#L139-L149) to go from the `st_mode` (integer) as reported by [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) into the familiar "stringy" format (I don't know if this representation has a proper name).

```
>>> stat.filemode(0o100644)
'-rw-r--r--'
```

Is there any "unfilemode" helper function to go the other way?

```
>>> unfilemode('-rw-r--r--')
33188
```

This is what I tried, but it's producing wrong results.  That's not treating the first character denoting file type correctly, and not handling sticky bits etc

```
table = {
    ord('r'): '1',
    ord('w'): '1',
    ord('x'): '1',
    ord('-'): '0',
}

def unfilemode(s):
    return int(s.translate(table), 2)
```

Comment: What are you getting the string from, and can that thing provide you with an alternate format instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is open-source, you can just read the source code for the `stat` module and write the inverse function.

See: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/stat.py#L112

```
import stat

def un_filemode(mode_str):
    mode = 0
    for char, table in zip(mode_str, stat._filemode_table):
        for bit, bitchar in table:
            if char == bitchar:
                mode |= bit
                break
    return mode
```

Note that I'm being "naughty" and accessing private members of the `stat` module. The usual caveats apply.

Also note that the documentation for `stat.filemode` is incorrect anyway, since `0o100000` is technically not part of the file mode, it is the file type `S_IFREG`. From [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html):

> POSIX refers to the stat.st_mode bits corresponding to the mask        `S_IFMT` (see below) as the file type, the 12 bits corresponding to the mask 07777 as the file mode bits and the least significant 9 bits (0777) as the file permission bits.

Comment: On my platform, the Python implementation of filemode is blown away by that [* import](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1f06a680de465be0c24a78ea3b610053955daa99/Lib/stat.py#L176) of a C implementation, and the behaviour of each implementation differs somewhat.  Go figure ..

Comment: @wim: That explains why it works correctly, since the Python code doesn't.